# S#arp Architecture NHibernate 3 and Linq Changes

Tags: linq, nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

I have just started to use the newest version of S#arp Architecture 1.9.5, which has made the change to NHibernate 3, this has a new Linq providor.

I just to be able to add custom methods in using the following code.

```
public class ClientBusinessTypeRepository : NHibernateRepository<ClientBusinessType>, IClientBusinessTypeRepository
    {
        public IList<ClientBusinessType> GetByName(string name)
        {
            return Session.Linq<ClientBusinessType>().Where(cbt=>cbt.Name == name).ToList();
        }

    }
```

Now I know I need to change the return line to use the new Linq, just not sure how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the 'Linq' method to 'Query'.